# MySQL Workbench o Community?

Tags: mysql

Por lo visto el Community trae de todo, cosas que de seguro nunca voy a usar. Solo quiero poder crear y trabajar con base de datos y Eclipse.

Qué debo instalar para crear base de datos y lograr la conexion con Eclipse?.
Solamente el Workbench o debe de ser el Community completo?. El Notifier es obligatorio?.

Comment: Debes instalar el que dice SERVER, en esta versión seria **MySQL Community Server** . Workbench es una interfaz grafica para conectarte al server y trabajar "mas rapido". Ademas para trbajar en java necesitas el [conector J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Answer (score 2):

Para trabajar con bases de datos, en este caso MySQL, necesitaras un servidor MySQL. Un servidor MySQL no es más que un programa que responde una y otra vez a todas tus peticiones SQL (Tu código SQL). Y por otro lado necesitarás un cliente para poder ver tus tablas, etc... Yo personalmente te recomiendo que uses XAMPP o MAMP o algún programa del estilo aunque yo te recomiendo uno de esos dos. Estos programas no solo te traen un servidor MySQL sino que te traen servidor Apache (web) y lo que realmente te podría venir bien un cliente llamado MySQLAdmin entre otras cosas. Como ya habrás podido leer, MySQL Workbench no es más que un cliente y Community es un servidor (desconozco si trae cliente) por lo que tendrías con un poco que mala suerte que usar los 2 (si no trae cliente) algo que con XAMPP o MAMP no pasaría desde un principio. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Wokbench es una herramienta que te permite interactuar con bases de datos MySql, Mysql Community es el servidor de base de datos que instalas al cual puedes acceder desde Workbench, segun este razonamiento, podrias dispensar de Workbench si asi quisieras, pero no del servidor MySql.

Comment: sigo sin entender, debo instalar el paquete completo entonces para poder crear bases de datos, hacer conectar eclipse con ellas?. El paquete incluye muchas cosas que no se lo que son, notifier, etc..

Comment: No necesariamente, puedes no usar la herramienta y conectarte al servidor via consola, crear base de datos y enviar queries, etc, aunque workbench puede facilitarte esto con una interfaz grafica.

Answer (score 1):

El MySQL Workbench ofrece dos versiones, la Enterprise y la Community.
Yo trabajo con base de datos MySQL y utilizo la versión Community. Con ella puedes diseñar la base de datos, crear las relaciones, actualizar las tablas, etc.
Si en caso la conexión falla por algún motivo puedes exportar el código y ejecutarlo en consola.
Es una herramienta recomendable.